# What is the difference between Snort rule and Emerging threats rules?

Tags: snort

[here is link for snort rules](http://www.snort.org)

[Emerging threat rule link](http://www.emergingthreats.net/)

i want to keep emerging threat rules in snort rule folder.is there any difference between these two rulesets?

Comment: Please add some information here in your description of the question for the people who want a little more information before clicking on the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them in the same folder it won't be a problem. Some of the emerging threat rules are for the same exploits as the snort provided rules. Typically the emerging threat rules aren't as good or efficient as the snort community rules and I would recommend using the snort provided rules over the emerging threat rules. There are some emerging threat rules that cover things that the snort community rules do not.

Typically the emerging threat rules will have SIDs in the 2 million range (so all emerging threat rules' sids start with 2).